# Trying to write a trigger in mySQL 5.6 to write out to another table after UPDATE

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm writing a trigger in mySQL 5.6 where after update of certain fields in table A, I will write table A's changes to a note table, however I'm getting an error on line 2 and I'm pretty sure it's something silly:

```
SET @createNote = 0;
SET @message = 'UPDATED';

IF (NEW.customerEmail != OLD.customerEmail) THEN
    SET @message = CONCAT(@message, '\r\n', OLD.customerEmail, ' -> ', NEW.customerEmail);
    SET @createNote = 1;
END IF;

IF (@createNote) THEN
    INSERT INTO claim_notes SET claimId = NEW.id, message = @message, createdBy = NEW.lastModifiedBy, type = 'system', createdByEmail = NEW.lastModifiedByEmail;
END IF;
```

---

I'm making use of Sequel Pro's trigger UI, so I don't have the normal delimiter stuff in my example.

---

Error Message:

> MySQL said: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'SET \@message = 'UPDATED'; IF (NEW.customerEmail !=
>   OLD.customerEmail) THEN SET' at line 2

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: @aendeerei 

MySQL said: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET \@message = 'UPDATED';

IF (NEW.customerEmail != OLD.customerEmail) THEN
 SET' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the trigger is multiple statements, I needed to wrap it with `BEGIN END`. I didn't realize that Sequel Pro didn't automatically wrap the triggers created through the UI.

```
BEGIN

    SET @createNote = 0;
    SET @message = 'UPDATED';

    IF (NEW.customerEmail != OLD.customerEmail) THEN
        SET @message = CONCAT(@message, '\r\n', OLD.customerEmail, ' -> ', NEW.customerEmail);
        SET @createNote = 1;
    END IF;

    IF (@createNote) THEN
        INSERT INTO claim_notes SET claimId = NEW.id, message = @message, createdBy = NEW.lastModifiedBy, type = 'system', createdByEmail = NEW.lastModifiedByEmail;
    END IF;

END;
```

---

I will be modifying my variable declaration per @BillKarwin's answer.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found the error. Yes, the trigger body must be a single statement or a single `BEGIN`/`END` block. The docs on `CREATE TRIGGER` are one of the most neglected parts of the MySQL manual. Not a single example!

Comment: Indeed! :-) Great work! Please don't forget to accept your own answer, so that other users benefit from the solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use apostrophe instead of quotes around "updated"

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got your statement to work after I changed the smart-quotes to straight single-quotes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON MyTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @createNote = 0;
  SET @message = "UPDATED";
  IF (NEW.customerEmail != OLD.customerEmail) THEN
    SET @message := CONCAT(@message, '\r\n', OLD.customerEmail, ' -> ', NEW.customerEmail);
    SET @createNote := 1;
  END IF;
  IF (@createNote) THEN
    INSERT INTO claim_notes SET claimId = NEW.id, message = @message, createdBy = NEW.lastModifiedBy, type = 'system', createdByEmail = NEW.lastModifiedByEmail;
  END IF;
END
```

Note these are smart-quotes: `‘’` They have no use in any coding language I know of.

And these are straight single-quotes: `''` They are used for string literals and date literals in SQL.

A few other recommendations:

- Use straight single-quotes for all strings.
- Use local variables instead of session variables.
- Your don't need `:=` for assignment, unless you're doing it within an expression. Just use `=` for a regular `SET` statement.

So I would write this trigger this way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON MyTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE _createNote INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE _message VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'UPDATED';
  IF (NEW.customerEmail != OLD.customerEmail) THEN
    SET _message = CONCAT(message, '\r\n', OLD.customerEmail, ' -> ', NEW.customerEmail);
    SET _createNote = 1;
  END IF;
  IF (_createNote) THEN
    INSERT INTO claim_notes SET claimId = NEW.id, message = _message, createdBy = NEW.lastModifiedBy, type = 'system', createdByEmail = NEW.lastModifiedByEmail;
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my edits didn't make it in before you took a look, the smart quotes were a byproduct of some copy-paste action on my part. I have also removed the `:=` from the code. 

Your answer did inform me on what I was doing wrong; the previous triggers I'd written were wrapped in an encompassing `IF`, so they were essentially single statements. I needed to wrap the code with a `BEGIN END;`